# Compile c code using r studio 4.03 for windows 10

Tags: r, c

I am using R. I need to compile a function written in C not c++.  I want to compile c code using 'R CMD SHLIB' this works well in my Ubuntu system but not working in my Window 10. How to compile the c code using r studio for windows 10? Thanks

Comment: Please descripe "not working" more precisely.

Comment: Have you installed Rtools 4?

Comment: Yes, I installed R tools 4 and modified my Windows environment variable. Now it works, thanks.